# Incremental crawl not working with two managed metadata services - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem were an incremental crawl doesn't pick up changes. My setup includes two different managed metadata services seperated in two proxy groups, each of them set as default in the different groups. One of the managed metadata services has two proxies, where the second one is used by proxy-group number two, not as default.

Proxy-group 1
[image]

Proxy-group 2
[image]

Both proxy groups share the same search service proxy.

In this setup, the incremental crawl cant seem to pick up changes, but the full crawl works just fine. I get it to work when i explicitly set the url to be crawled in the next incremental crawl (in the crawl log view in CA),

This is not a termstore update, just changing the content in a field on a page.

When i delete the second metadata service and the second proxy service on the first metadata service, the incremental crawl starts working again.

I cant seem to find any good information in the logs on why this is.

Anyone has an any idea of why this is happening, or cant point me in the right direction?

Thanks.